# jQuery UI sortable prevent drop into connected sortable if item has already some childs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need your help. I'm currently trying to make a sortable list of items. Each item can also be a child item of another one:

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        $( '#import-sort-wrapper' ).sortable( {
            placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
            connectWith: '.import-sort-item-variations',
            start: function ( e, ui ) {
                ui.placeholder.height( ui.item.height() );
            },
            beforeStop: function ( e, ui ) {
                console.log( 'before stop' );
                // Check if product has already variations
                if (ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first li' ).length > 0) {
                    $( ui.sender ).sortable( 'cancel' );
                }
            },
            stop: function ( e, ui ) {
                let itemVariations = ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first' );

                // Check if item is variable product and display / hide variations list
                if (ui.item.closest( '.import-sort-item-variations' ).length === 1) {
                    // itemVariations.empty();
                    itemVariations.hide();
                } else {
                    itemVariations.show();
                }
            }
        } );

        $( '.import-sort-item-variations' ).sortable( {
            placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
            connectWith: '#import-sort-wrapper',
            start: function ( e, ui ) {
                ui.placeholder.height( ui.item.height() );
            },
            stop: function ( e, ui ) {
                let itemVariations = ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first' );

                // Show variation option again in case item is moved out of variation list
                if (ui.item.closest( '.import-sort-item-variations' ).length === 0) {
                    itemVariations.show();
                }
            }
        } );
    } );
});
```

```css
#import-sort-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 9px 0 0;
  cursor: move;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.import-sort-item {
  background: #f6f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcde;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.import-sort-item .import-sort-item-header .sort-item-header-id {
  font-weight: 600;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.import-sort-item .import-sort-item-header .sort-item-header-type {
  color: #50575e;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.import-sort-item .import-sort-item-variations {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcde;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.import-sort-item .import-sort-item-variations li {
  margin: 10px;
}
#import-sort-wrapper li.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  border: 1px dashed #c3c4c7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="import-sort-wrapper">
    <li class="import-sort-item">
        <span class="import-sort-item-header">
            <span class="sort-item-header-id">30:</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-name">Testprodukt</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-type">Variables Produkt</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="import-sort-item-variations">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="import-sort-item">
        <span class="import-sort-item-header">
            <span class="sort-item-header-id">28:</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-name">Erdbeeren</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-type">Variables Produkt</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="import-sort-item-variations">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="import-sort-item">
        <span class="import-sort-item-header">
            <span class="sort-item-header-id">29:</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-name">Variables Produkt</span>
            <span class="sort-item-header-type">Variables Produkt</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="import-sort-item-variations">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I somehow want to prevent any drag-n-drop of an element which already has some childs into another main element. It should only be possible if the element which should be dragged has **no childs!** I've tried checking some things inside the `beforeStop` callback, but somehow I don't get this thing working correctly. Any ideas? Maybe I'm on the wrong way and this is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Thanks to Funky for the hint. Also I've moved the function to the child sortable and used a different callback `received` since `sortable('cancel')` causes some JS errors when used in `beforeStop`:

```
receive: function ( e, ui ) {
    console.log( ui.sender );
    // Check if product has already variations
    if (ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first li' ).length > 0) {
        $( '#product-import-sort-wrapper' ).sortable( 'cancel' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you change your code

```
  beforeStop: function ( e, ui ) {
            console.log( 'before stop' );
            // Check if product has already variations
            if (ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first li' ).length > 0) {
                $( ui.sender ).sortable( 'cancel' );
            }
        },
```

To :

```
 beforeStop: function ( e, ui ) {
            console.log( 'before stop' );
            // Check if product has already variations
            if (ui.item.find( '.import-sort-item-variations:first li' ).length > 0) {
                 $( '#import-sort-wrapper' ).sortable('cancel')
            }
        },
```

Is that what you want? ?

Comment: Partly, somehow it's now not possible anymore to move the parent element with some childs in it in the parent area.